# Django: timezone.now() does not return current datetime

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-rest-framework

Through a Django Rest Framework API, I am trying to serve all objects with a datetime in the future.

**Problem is, once the server has started up, every time I submit the query, the API will serve all objects whose datetime is greater than the datetime at which the server started instead of the objects whose datetime is greater than the current time.**

```
from django.utils import timezone

class BananasViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = Banana.objects.filter(date_and_time__gte=timezone.now())
    ...
```

Without any more luck, I also tried this variation:

```
import datetime as dt

class BananasViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = Banana.objects.filter(date_and_time__gte=
        timezone.make_aware(dt.datetime.now(), timezone.get_current_timezone())
    ...
```

Making a similar query in a Django shell correctly returns the objects up to date...

Comment: So, do you mean the `timezone.now()` should return current time instead the time which server started?

Comment: Indeed I thought `timezone.now()` should return current time. That's what it does in the shell.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the application code is currently written you're running `timezone.now()` once, when the class is first imported from anywhere.

Rather than apply the time queryset filtering on the class attribute itself, do so in the `get_queryset()` method so that it'll be re-evaluated on each pass.

Eg.

```
class BananasViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = Banana.objects.all()

    def get_queryset(self):
        cutoff = timezone.now()
        return self.queryset.filter(date_and_time__gte=cutoff)
```

Comment: it is better to use `timezone.now()` with `USE_TZ=True` instead of `make_aware(datetime.now(), get_current_timezone())`. The latter is wrong if the current timezone is different from the default timezone and even then it may fail during DST transitions.

Comment: Noted. I figured I'd just replicate the opening questions' style, but I've updated the answer now.

Answer (score 3):

```
timezone.now()
```

This function returns the current time. It does not return the time when the server started. So according to your query you are asking for the filter on the model Banana with `date_and_time` field greater than the current time.

This query practically seems inappropriate because no object can be created at a time in which `date_and_time` field is greater than or equal to `timezone.now()`

Comment: In my example, bananas are events and I only want to display future events. This has nothing to do with the time at which the objects were created.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't something like this be better placed into a constructor so you can predict when timezone.now() is actually called?

```
from django.utils import timezone

class BananasViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):

    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super(BananasViewSet,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.queryset = Banana.objects.filter(date_and_time__gte=timezone.now())
```